# Plot of a function w.r.t x^2

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function with respect to x^2 i.e., Plot[f(x),{x^2,0,1}], but mathematica is giving error. Suggestions please

Comment: How about `Plot[{f[Sqrt[x]], f[-Sqrt[x]]}, {x, 0, 1}]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
ParametricPlot[{x^2, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a function f(x) in Lingua-Mathematica:

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

and you want to plot that function over the range `{f(x),0,1}`,

```
Plot[f[x], {f[x], 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note:

> Plot[f,{x,Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]}] generates a plot of f
>   as a function of x from Subscript[x, min] to Subscript[x, max].
>
> Plot[{Subscript[f, 1],Subscript[f, 2],[Ellipsis]},{x,Subscript[x,
>   min],Subscript[x, max]}] plots several functions Subscript[f, i].
>
> Plot[[Ellipsis],{x}[Element]reg] takes the variable x to be in the
>   geometric region reg.

```
Plot[Sin[time], {time, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[Sqrt[x]], f[-0.5 Sqrt[x]]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], f[-Sqrt[x]], f'[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: @TomD, no typo see note and second plot, it is what the OP is asking for, and since i'm scaling x-axis with f(x) it has to look like that.

Comment: OK, I see it now!